# Why does Jquery submit() fail with an error?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a simple form on a page and I want to auto submit it when some event occurs.

The test code below tries to submit the form as soon as the page loads, but it fails. Firebug says that "H[G] is not a function". H[G] appears to be "submit".

Am I doing something really obviously stupid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/test.php" method="post" id="packingform">
        <input name="bob" value="1" type="text" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="hello" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        // This line fails with an error and the form is not submitted
        $("#packingform").submit();
    }
    );
    // ]]>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it.

Turns out that if you have a named submit button in your form, submit() will fail. Here is a link to the bug report on jquery: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4652

The solution is to change `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="hello" />` 
to `<input type="submit" value="hello" />`

I hope this helps someone else...

Comment: ...the form is still not posting in FF with the "/" in 'action'...or is this only happening on my pc ?

Comment: and as regards the naming issue, the problem is only when the submit button is named "submit"; if it's named something else, the form still posts without any trouble

Comment: All feels a bit flaky to me. I might have to look at jQuery's source to figure out why it would be so sensitive. It worked in FF and Safari here when I changed the submit name, and those are the only 2 browsers I need to support for this project (internal).

Comment: Note that the bug fires when you have **any** field named _submit_. e.g. I had the problem with a `hidden` field named _submit_ as well.

Comment: @rikh I'm having this issue but my submit button is definately not called submit. Any other ideas? It's working in IE, FF and Chrome just not in Safari and it's frustrating me! :D

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with `action="/test.php"`on Firefox, because it works on both Chrome and IE

Try changing it to `action="test.php"` and try again.

Comment: when i set the action to test.php, the form submitted here

Comment: what jquery version are u using by any chance?  I tried it with 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is something wrong with your jQuery.js file. Maybe try replacing the jQuery.js file with a fresh copy downloaded from the [jQuery website](http://www.jquery.com).

Answer (score 0):

hi it is great indeed very helpfull,
 i wasted around 16 hours looking at what happend and the solution was to change name of submit button 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and my submit button doesn't have a "name", it only have "id".

Anyway this solved my issue:

```
$("#submitButton").click();
```